# SQL Server max databases number reached

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server (LocalDB) in some unit tests. Every test attach a database to LocalDB. It's about 400 new databases per execution. I know, it's not the best approach.

After many days running testes I got:

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException : Unable to create/attach any new database because the number of existing databases has reached the maximum number allowed: 32766.
```

I attach my MDF files with this connection string:

```
string.Format(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename={0}.mdf;Integrated Security=True", TempFile)
```

I tried detach all databases, but it didn't work. I used:

```
EXEC sp_detach_db 'MyFile.MDF', 'true';
```

I also tried delete my LocalDB instance and didn't work too. To delete I used:

Stop:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe stop "v11.0" -k
```

Delete:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe delete "v11.0"
```

Create:

```
SqlLocalDB.exe create "v11.0" -s
```

Any idea to solve this issue?

Comment: Wouldn't a clear down script be quicker than creating a new database/schema each time!? Also the pedant in me suggests that you're probably talking about Integration Tests rather than Unit Tests if you're connecting to the db...

Comment: Make sure you drop the databases in your test's Teardown method

Comment: @Liath LocalDB *is* used in Unit tests so you neither need a full database nor create complex mocks where a few SQL statements would be enough. Besides, how are you going to unit test the stored procedures/UDFs/Views used by the rest of your program?

Comment: Yes, its Integration test. I forgot do delete and now I'm getting this error. I want to solve this issue without uninstalling SQL Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you removing LocaDB from same use that created it?

Comment: Thanks, this solved. I was removing from my user, not tests user.